# How to get photo of place from google places api

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, var, geturl

I'm beginer to js and api

I have an for me big problem..

How to get photo for some places with google places api.

I try with this:

```
function setLink(i) {
            var photo = place.photos;
            var sideClick = jQuery("<a class=side_click href='#'></a>");
             $(sideClick).html(place.name+photo);
             $("#side_bar").append(sideClick).append("<br>");
             $(sideClick).on("click", function() {
               markers[i].modalWindow_.getDetails(markers[i].place_);
             });
          }
```

and I get only something like this:

```
Hotel Name [object Object]
```

How to change this [object Object] into url of image?

also i try with:

```
var photo = place.photos.geturl();
```

but also dont work...

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`place.photos` is an Array , you must select an item of the array to get details for a particular photo

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_photos

Comment: yes but I was try with place.photos[1]; and then just get : undefined :)

Comment: thanks I get it with: var photo = place.photos[0].getUrl({
            'maxWidth': 35,
            'maxHeight': 35
        });

Comment: I dont know why my script now have a auto refresh every 5 seconds ??? and why when I type "paris, france" map won't to show it ??? please help